# Polygon annotorious with openseadragon

Tags: annotations, annotorious

I am using annotorious with openseadragon. I am facing issue with polygonSelector plugin.

```
anno.addPlugin('PolygonSelector', { activate: true });
```

If I use add plugin code in window load it says 'annotator.addSelector is not a function'. 
    If I use add plugin code while click add annote button it says Could not load plugin: PolygonSelector.